# Hibernate Beans generator

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, javabeans

Does anybody know if there is any program able to create beans classes from a SQL file ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html):

> Reverse Engineering: The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is a database reverse engineering tool that can generate domain model classes and Hibernate mapping files, annotated EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation or even an entire JBoss Seam application in seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Hibernate tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html), which has a "Reverse Engineering" feature to do exactly this.